# Как распределить элементы по принципу младшего разряда?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Итак, допустим, у нас есть некий список `[32, 45, 64, 76, 57, 28]`. Как распределить их по 10 корзинам, по принципу младшего разряда, то есть

```
Корзина 1 - 
Корзина 2 - 32
Корзина 3 - 
Корзина 4 - 64
Корзина 5 - 45
Корзина 6 - 76
Корзина 7 - 57
Корзина 8 - 28
Корзина 9
Корзина 10
```

После записать их в новый список. После по той же схеме, только уже по старшему разряду. Помогите пожалуйста с этой частью. Как я понял, можно использовать очереди, но не понимаю, как реализовать

Comment: Непонятно, к чему тут очереди. Выделяете разряд, кладёте в корзину.

Comment: Где ваши попытки решения задачи?

Answer (score 1):

```
baskets=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
arr=[32, 45, 64, 76, 57, 28, 65, 94,127, 8]
for i in arr:
    baskets[i%10].append(i)
print (baskets)
```

Результат:

```
[[], [], [32], [], [64, 94], [45, 65], [76], [57, 127], [28, 8], []]
```

*После по той же схеме, только уже по старшему разряду.*  -  надеюсь справитесь сами.

*Как я понял, можно использовать очереди, но не понимаю, как реализовать*  - и я не понимаю, и главное - зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вообще словарь использовал. Зачем нужны пустые корзины?

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = [32, 45, 64, 76, 57, 28, 74, 55, 22]
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for v in my_list:
    my_dict[v%10].append(v)
print(dict(my_dict))
```

Вывод:

```
{2: [32, 22], 5: [45, 55], 4: [64, 74], 6: [76], 7: [57], 8: [28]}
```

Ну или вот так, чтобы прям в нужном виде вывод был:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(f'Корзина {i} - {",".join(map(str,my_dict[i]))}')
```

Вывод:

```
Корзина 0 - 
Корзина 1 - 
Корзина 2 - 32,22
Корзина 3 - 
Корзина 4 - 64,74
Корзина 5 - 45,55
Корзина 6 - 76
Корзина 7 - 57
Корзина 8 - 28
Корзина 9 -
```

Comment: Я тоже об этом подумал. Но судя по вопросу(вопросам) ТС, для него это будет слишком. Хотел даже уточнить, а что в его понимании есть "корзина", но пощадил. И решил, что 10 корзин - не смертельная доза, тем более, что это константное количество (пока он не перейдет  к другой системе счисления :-) ).